# Is it possible to only change the guibg of the current window?

Tags: vimscript

As title. Say I have 2 (vertical) window splits, I just want to change the background color of the right one. Is this even possible? If so, How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is `:h 'wincolor'` in Vim. And `:h 'winhighlight'` in Neovim.

```
:execute printf("hi RandomBg guibg=#%x", rand() % 0xFFFFFF)
:let w = winnr("l")
:if has("nvim")
:  call setwinvar(w, "&winhighlight", "Normal:RandomBg")
:else
:  call setwinvar(w, "&wincolor", "RandomBg")
:endif
```

Comment: Sorry for my late upvote! Great, a very happy news after work :)